# How to fill out a text field with the name of the current InfoPath form view?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, infopath, custom-form, infopath-view

We have a SharePoint list with an associated InfoPath form.

The form has multiple views based on different field values and rules e.g. view_item (all fields), new_item, edit_a, edit_b and edit_c.

How can I store the name of the view in a hidden text field in the form?

We are using SharePoint 2013 and InfoPath 2013.

Best regards
Morten

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not understanding your case but why not just add an field and hidden control to each view and enter the view name there manually? If you need it dynamically try using the XmlForm.CurrentView Property in default value function for the field.

Comment: Thank you, Marek Sarad. I found two existing fields which could define my views.